# How to SaveAs a new Excel file with edits without changing original?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel for Microsoft 365.
In some prior version of Excel I used to make edits in a workbook (call it workbook A), choose SaveAs, rename the file (call it workbook B).
I could then I open workbook A and find it in a state of pre-edits while workbook B saved with edits.

The code below saves workbook A with the edits that are in workbook B.
I want to keep workbook A unchanged.

```vb
Sub NoticeGenerator()
Dim wxhS As Worksheet, wbkT As Workbook
Const TABCOLOR As Long = 192 'Standard Tab color Dark Red
    
'Hides any tabs that are Dark Red
For Each wxhS In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wxhS.Tab.Color <> TABCOLOR Then
        wxhS.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
    If wxhS.Tab.Color = TABCOLOR Then
        wxhS.Cells.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
Next      
  
'Displaying the saveas dialog box
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Notice Generator v", _
  "Excel files,*.xlsm", 1, "Select your folder and filename")

'Saves file if filename is entered, otherwise it won't save
If FName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End If

For Each wxhS In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wxhS.Tab.Color = TABCOLOR Then
        wxhS.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        wxhS.Protect
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Once workbook A opened, do Save As "B", so active workbook becomes B, later simply do adjustments on it >Save>Close

Comment: Well that's the manual way I used to do it.  But it doesn't work that way in the latest version of excel, and it certainly doesn't work that way in this code.

Comment: For the change in behaviour you've observed, have you considered turning off AutoSave (which seems to enable itself automatically when you save to OneDrive)
For the desired behaviour, have you considered the SaveCopyAs method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas

Comment: I will try the turning autosave off and relay the results.  as for SaveCopyAs - I have considered it but it looks rigid by requiring an explicit directory which would change in my case relative to who is working on the file.

Comment: Turning off AutoSave - this is the answer.  It makes the "Save As" work both manually and in code.  It actually changes what options you have for saving.  With AutoSave on, you only get "Save a Copy" but with it off you get an option to "Save" and one to "Save As".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off AutoSave - this is the answer. It makes the "Save As" work both manually and in code. It actually changes what options you have for saving. With AutoSave on, you only get "Save a Copy" but with it off you get an option to "Save" and one to "Save As".

The final code I used below turns AutoSave off before moving on:

```
Sub NoticeGenerator()
    Dim wxhS As Worksheet, wbkT As Workbook
    Const TABCOLOR As Long = 192 'Standard Tab color Dark Red

'Turns off AutoSave because with it on it would compromise the original file while saving
    If Val(Application.Version) > 15 Then
        ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
    End If   
 
 'Hides any tabs that are Dark Red
   For Each wxhS In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wxhS.Tab.Color <> TABCOLOR Then
            wxhS.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            
        End If
        If wxhS.Tab.Color = TABCOLOR Then
            wxhS.Cells.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            
        End If
    
    Next
          
'Displaying the SaveAs dialog box
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Notice Generator v", _
    "Excel files,*.xlsm", 1, "Select your folder and filename")

'Saves file if filename is entered, otherwise it won't save - only works if AutoSave is turned off first in code above
If FName <> False Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
     End If

'Soft Protects without password red tabbed sheets to avoid compromising the file accidentally
 For Each wxhS In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wxhS.Tab.Color = TABCOLOR Then
            wxhS.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
            wxhS.Protect
        End If
 Next


End Sub
```